# Get WooCommerce Subscription without Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get the subscription information from the Wordpress's WooCommerce plugin, but I don't want to load the crazy load of files that WP loads and slows down the server. What I currently use is as follows:

```
$subscription = false;
$result = WC_Subscriptions_Manager::get_users_subscriptions( $userID );
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {       
    if ($result[$key]["status"]=="active") $subscription = true;
}
```

But is there any way, will I be able to do it without including the following crazy code:

```
require('wp-load.php');
```

I just wanna connect to the DB and find out something. What I have now in WooCommerce entry for me is a big text chunk of:

> `a:1:{s:7:"609_222";a:11:{s:10:"product_id";s:3:"22";s:9:"order_key";s:19:"order_5396dcccd4049";s:8:"order_id";i:609;s:10:"start_date";s:19:"2014-06-10 10:37:51";s:11:"expiry_date";i:0;s:8:"end_date";i:0;s:6:"status";s:6:"active";s:17:"trial_expiry_date";i:0;s:15:"failed_payments";i:0;s:18:"completed_payments";a:1:{i:0;s:19:"2014-06-10 10:37:52";}s:16:"suspension_count";i:0;}}`

I have no clue on how to get this piece of code working without using `wp-load.php`. Any heads up?

Comment: How about building a mysql query and grabbing/unserializing the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is serialize so `maybe_deserialize` and `is_serialize` function should work, just copie them:
[Codex](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0.1/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L265)

**EDIT :**

Your serialize have an error here :
`s:3:"22"`

s => String

3 => length of 3

but you have just two char.

Change 3 by 2 then you can unserialize

(it's maybe corrupt data on your database, try with other user to see if it's ok )

Online deserializer to test:
http://www.unserialize.com/s/54d4be2e-bc4a-8208-93eb-00000a0c6243

Comment: I don't wanna use any `WP` files. Do you have a solution?

Comment: Create your own wpdb function and connect to the database should work then

Comment: Well wait. I asked what am I supposed to put in `wpdb`?

Comment: I already have a connection using MySQLi with the object `$conn`. Any ideas with that?

Comment: Then you just have to execute the query I've posted `"SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = '$use_id' and meta_key = 'whatever'"`

Comment: Boss, I am not talking about getting the `meta_value`! I got that. I need to know the logic behind the subscription! Every user has that subscription string. I need to know if this subscription string has got an active subscription or not. With the output of WC's function, I check if there's an `active` or not. I need that logic. Can you help?

Comment: The link says Trac Error! `:(`

Comment: This says not a valid serialized object!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65867/discussion-between-xcid-and-praveen-kumar).

Comment: Yes buddy... Come in Chat now.

Answer (score 0):

Example query, edit for wherever woocommerce resides.

```
<?php
require 'wp-config.php';
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$link) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$link);
$r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = '_site_transient_update_core'");
$a = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
$data = unserialize($a['option_value']);
print_r($data);
?>
```